# UIActionSheet orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way to set the orientation of the UIActionSheet programatically?
My iPhone orientation is Portrait, but the UIActionSheet need to be Landscape. Can this be done?

Edit:

So my problem is that I don't want to rotate the rootviewcontroller to landscape mode, only the UIActionSheet. So is this possible somehow?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you're trying to do? Why not just code the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method so that the application only supports landscape? That way the application will always be in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I added a view to my view in which I want to display the UIActionSheet, then rotated the added view and then added the UIActionSheet in this view.

Comment: Is this still working in iOS 4.x and 5?  I did the same thing and it seems that the UIActionSheet is taking its orientation from the view controller and not the view.