# UIActionSheet orientation

Tags: iphone

I am having a problem trying to get the orientation of the device correct. I have to show an action sheet that should come depending on the orientation of the device. Here is the code I am using.

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

  switch (orientation) 

  {
   case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
   case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
   case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown: 
   case UIDeviceOrientationUnknown:
   case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:

   [self displayActionSheetInPotraitMode];
   break;

   case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
   case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:

   [self displayActionSheetInLandscapeMode];
   break;

   default:

   [self displayActionSheetInPotraitMode];
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look what the [UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) tells us about the `orientation` property.

> The value of this property always returns 0 unless orientation notifications have been enabled by calling beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications.

So, you should call

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]
```

somewhere earlier in your code.

---

Also, I'd like to suggest a way to simplify your current code:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    [self displayActionSheetInLandscapeMode];
} else {
    [self displayActionSheetInPotraitMode];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: [UIActionSheet orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004671/uiactionsheet-orientation)

You should add a UIView (add it as subview to UIWindow) -> transform it to proper orientation and then add the UIActionSheet to this UIView.